# How to use Log4net to log in File in Windows Application

Tags: c#, nhibernate, log4net

I'm trying to use Log4net for the first time in my WinForm application, before that I thought to see if it works in my Console application which didn't even produce any log file.

I have referred other posts as well to achieve logging but to no avail.

To get NHibernate generated queries logged into the file, I added following in my Config File as suggested in the [post](http://nhibernate.info/doc/howto/various/configure-log4net-for-use-with-nhibernate.html):

**Config File**

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate" />
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4" />
        <bindingRedirect newVersion="3.4.0.0" oldVersion="3.1.0.4000" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=NHibernateIntro;Integrated Security=True</property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</property>
      <property name="show_sql">true</property>
      <property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
      <property name="cache.use_query_cache" >true</property>
      <property name="cache.provider_class">NHibernate.Caches.SysCache.SysCacheProvider, NHibernate.Caches.SysCache</property>
      <!-- <mapping assembly="NHibernateTest"/>-->
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>

  <log4net debug="false">

    <!-- Define some output appenders -->
    <appender name="trace"
          type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender, log4net">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
             value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="console"
          type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender, log4net">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
             value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="rollingFile"
          type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net" >

      <param name="File" value="log.txt" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="false" />
      <param name="RollingStyle" value="Date" />
      <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyy.MM.dd" />
      <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="true" />

      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
          value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- Setup the root category, add the appenders and set the default priority -->
    <root>
      <priority value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>
    <logger name="NHibernate">
      <level value="WARN" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="NHibernate.SQL">
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="rollingFile" />
    </logger>

  </log4net>

</configuration>
```

Then I added the following in AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

That's all I was suggested in the above post. But It didn't work. Am I missing some thing?

**Updated:**

Following is the simple class with simple methods in which I'm using NHibernate and want the resulting queries to be shown in file:

```
   public class Merger
    {
        public static void Run(ISessionFactory factory)
        {
            Customer customer;

            using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
            using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                customer = session.Get<Customer>(6946816);
            }

            customer.FirstName = "example";

            using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
            using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
            {

               object anothercustomer = session.Merge(customer);
               session.SaveOrUpdate(anothercustomer);
               tx.Commit();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems that you have just one appender in use - defined on *root* - the console. Try to extend logger `<logger name="NHibernate.SQL">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="rollingFile" />
  </logger>`

Comment: @Radim As suggested by you, I updated the config but that didn't work either. In config its written : value="log.txt" which means it should create log file where my project belongs. Should I use any logger method or something to get the logs written in log file, Or is it done seamlessly because I didn't use any method or something

Comment: Sorry, not sure what is wrong... Hope you will get better answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed this from AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

And added the following just before creating Configuration instance:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
var cfg = new Configuration();   // creating Configuration instance
```

And it created the folder containing log file. I even changed attribute:

```
<appendToFile value="false"
```

to

```
<appendToFile value="true"
```

so that file will not be overwritten.